# How do I clone a hard disk excluding some directories?

Tags: macos, backup, disk-utility

In preparation for Lion, I want to make a bootable clone of my system to an external harddisk. I use TimeMachine, but I want to be sure I have a running backup.

Of course, there is much stuff on my system which doesn't need to be secured. This includes ~/Library/Caches and especially the installation of the developer tools (/Developer). To save space, I don't want to clone these.

Which tool can I use to do that? I have always cloned my harddisks with Disk Utility, but you obviously can't exclude directories with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/) and [SuperDuper](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) can clone and omit files or directories from the clone.

Comment: Is the backup bootable when using the "incremental backup of selected objects"-option of CCC?

Comment: I think so http://help.bombich.com/kb/troubleshooting/what-makes-a-volume-bootable

Comment: I temper that 'FTW' now that CCC costs ~$40 (double what OS X costs)!